# SD card is damaged

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a 2gb sd card and from yesterday whenever I was putting my Android 4.0.4 phone on standby it was showing a notification that Sd card is removed unexpectedly and after a few seconds sd card inserted. and now its showing that your sd card is damaged and asking if to format it or not. please suggest something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think formatting is your last resort. SD cards do have a limited life, and only can perform so many read/writes before they give up the ghost.

Try to backup your SD card on your PC if you can. You could use an SD card reader.

Try your SD on another phone and see if it works. If it does, you know something with your phone is not right. Use this opportunity to back up the SD!

Try a different SD on your phone and see how that works.

Lastly, you could format the SD card and see if that helps, but you will permanently lose all data on it. If your ROM has an `sd-ext` partition, your OS will not boot. (Unlikely in this specific case, but worth noting for others.)